# Javascript BMI Calculator Beginners Q:

Tags: javascript, html, css

Beginner javascripter here, I've lurked this site immensely and its helped me many a time. 
I've been coding for a few days now and decided to create a BMI Calculator as a test project.
The calcuator works fine, but when adding a return false statement or attempting to accomplish two functions on the same button, I appear to run into issues.
Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function BMIstuff() {

        BMIValidate(
            If(document.bmiForm.name.value.length <= 0) alert("please enter a name"); If(document.bmiForm.name.value = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;) {
                return true;
            } else {
                aert("Please enter a name with valid characters")




                BMI Calculate(
                    if (document.bmiForm.weight.value.length < 1 || document.bmiForm.weight.value.length >= 4)
                        alert("enter a valid weight");
                    if (document.bmiForm.height.value.length < 1 || document.bmiForm.height.value.length >= 5)
                        alert("enter a valid height");
                    if (document.bmiForm.weight.value < 50 || document.bmiForm.weight.value >= 260)
                        alert("enter a valid weight value");
                    if (document.bmiForm.height.value < 1 || document.bmiForm.height.value >= 5)
                        alert("enter a valid height value");
                    return false;

                    var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
                    var height = document.bmiForm.height.value

                    if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
                        var finalBmi = weight / (height * height)
                        document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
                        if (finalBmi < 18.5) {
                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "You are underweight"
                        }
                        if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi <= 24.9) {
                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "You are in a healthy weight range"
                        }
                        if (finalBmi > 25 && finalBmi <= 29.9) {
                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "You are overweight"
                        }
                        if (finalBmi > 30) {
                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "You are obese"
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Please ensure that your height and weight are in a valid range, also, ensure that you are not using any invalid symbols or characters. ")
                    )
                }
            }
            //-->
</script>
```

```
<h1> BMI Calculator </h1>

<form name="bmiForm">
    Enter your Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" size="25">
    <br />Height(m):
    <input type="text" name="height" size="10">
    <br />Weight(kg):
    <input type="text" name="weight" size="10">
    <br />

    <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="BMIstuff()">
    <br />Your BMI:
    <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10">
    <br />What does this mean?
    <input type="text" name="meaning" size="45">
    <br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Apologies, for the large amount of code, wasn't sure what wouldn't be necessary in order to correct my errors.
Thank you kindly.

Comment: "I appear to run into issues" What issues would that be?

Comment: Your javascript is riddled with typos and missing semicolons.

Comment: Just so ya know, the BMI formula was invented in 1848 by Adolphe Quetelet who was studying beauty, not medicine.

Answer (score 0):

Three code-breakers:

- `If`: does not exist, use lowercase `if`
- `BMI Calculate(`: a function cannot have a space in its name
- `aert`: does not exist, should be `alert`

You'd notice all those errors if you opened the Dev console in your browser.

Also, like Andrew pointed out in the comments, you're missing a lot of semicolons. Although Javascript will usually work without them, but it's a really bad practice and you don't want to make it a habit.